# always-on Dictaphone

Tags: audio, voice-recording

I know there is an app named [Dictaphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.bgadzala.android.dictaphone.free). I need a feature like that, but it should be on all day long. Because when it's time to turn it on, I always forget to start this app. And so I can't record important dialog. It must be kind an audioregistrator from the pocket.

I know apps that [register video](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rubberbigpepper.VideoReg). I need the same thing but only that it records audio without video. For example it must record every hour and save records on flash card with names like 2013-02-15_08-09. That means recording on 15 February 2013 from 8 a.m. to 9 a.m. And for example if there is no more space on flash card it must erase several recordings to continue recording.

Comment: efr, questions of the kind *Can you suggest an app that does X?* are off topic here according to our [FAQ]. I rephrased your question a little to avoid it being closed (asking for a *solution to your problem* instead of asking for an app with special features). I cannot answer your question, though -- but wish you good luck!

Comment: I don't see how such an app would work unless it prevents the phone from sleeping, and then it's going to run out of battery long before the day is over. You're going to be better off with a device designed for such a purpose.

Comment: Is it on specific times that you have to start recording? Otherwise I think you would be better of using an app like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to schedule when it should start recording. Battery drain and out of memory will otherwise be some problems. ("Privacy" pops in my head too btw)